# Breaking from Switch at the right time

Tags: java, switch-statement, break

I am doing a sort of non-recursive approach to the Towers of Hanoi. I know that... 1) We move the first disk to the next available space (that is neither the last/current place the disk was in). 2) Move the next possible disk (that is not the first disk). 3) Repeat. I have a system which consists of a `List` of `Stack`s (these are the rods) and each `Stack` holds `Disk` objects.

The question: How can I `break` the `Switch` only after either an `if` or a `catch` is executed? Keeping in mind that the second `try` has to be reachable if the first `if` is `false`.

```
switch(i){
  case 0: {
    try {
      if(gameObject.get(i).peek().getName() < 
         gameObject.get(i+1).peek().getName()){
// Move disk (i) to Stack (i+1) and exit switch.
      }
    } catch(EmptyStackException e){
// Move disk (i) to Stack (i+1) and exit switch. 


       }
    try {
      if(gameObject.get(i).peek().getName() < 
         gameObject.get(i+2).peek().getName()){
// Move disk (i) to Stack (i+2) and exit switch.
      }
    } catch(EmptyStackException e){
// Move disk (i) to Stack (i+2) and exit switch.                   
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding your overall design: 1) I'm not sure you need a switch()/case block at all.  Perhaps if/else might be better suited?  2) You should definitely consider *minimizing* the number of try/catch blocks.  Ideally, you can eliminate it altogether, and let a higher-level caller handle an EmptyStackException.

Comment: @paulsm4 I updated my question to reflect exactly what I want to do with each catch. Hopefully, that clears up the reason why I am doing it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encapsulate the entire switch block in a try catch block, you're unnecessarily duplicating code here. This also means if an exception is caught it will automatically break from the switch.

If you want the if statements to break switch execution, just include a break:

```
    int j;
    try {
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                for(j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
                    if(gameObject.get(i).peek().getName() < 
                       gameObject.get(i+j).peek().getName()){
                        // do something
                        break;
                    }
                }
            default: 
                // do something
        }
    } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
        int peekThatFailed = j;  //Showing you can use j to determine which peek failed.
    }
```

EDIT: Could use a for loop in the switch case to simplify the consecutive if statements and keep track of index peeked.

Comment: No, because I want check and handle the `catch` case for each `Stack`.

Comment: Basically I want to check if the `Disk` I am holding can be moved to the current `Stack` but I want to force move it when the `peek()` throws an exception.